# How to print elements from tcl_obj in gdb?

Tags: gdb, tcl

I am debugging a c++-tcl interface application and I need to see the elements of `Tcl_Obj` `objv`.
I tried doing `print *(objv[1])` and so on but it doesnt seem helping.
Is there any way to see `Tcl_Obj` elements in gdb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not particularly easy to understand a `Tcl_Obj *` from GDB as the data structure uses polymorphic pointers with shrouded types. (Yeah, this is tricky C magic.) However, there are definitely some things you can try. (I'll pretend that the pointer is called `objPtr` below, and that it is of type `Tcl_Obj *`.)

Firstly, check out what the `objPtr->typePtr` points to, if anything. A `NULL` `objPtr->typePtr` means that the object *just* has something in the `objPtr->bytes` field, which is a UTF-8 string containing `objPtr->length` bytes with a `\0` at `objPtr->bytes[objPtr->length]`. A `Tcl_Obj *` should *never* have both its `objPtr->bytes` and `objPtr->typePtr` being `NULL` at the same time.

If the `objPtr->typePtr` is not `NULL`, it points to a static constant structure that defines the basic polymorphic type operations on the `Tcl_Obj *` (think of it as being like a vtable). Of initial interest to you is going to be the `name` field though; that's a human-readable `const char *` string, and it will probably help you a lot. The other things in that structure include a definition of how to duplicate the object and how to serialize the object. (The `objPtr->bytes` field *really* holds the serialization.)

The `objPtr->typePtr` defines the interpretation of the `objPtr->internalRep`, which is a C `union` that is big enough to hold two generic pointers (and a few other things besides, like a `long` and `double`; you'll also see a `Tcl_WideInt`, which is probably a `long long` but that depends on the compiler). How this happens *is up to the implementation of the type* so it's difficult to be all-encompassing here, but it's basically the case that small integers have the `objPtr->internalRep.longValue` field as meaningful, floating point numbers have the `objPtr->internalRep.doubleValue` as meaningful, and more complex types hang a structure off the side.

With a list, the structure actually hangs off the `objPtr->internalRep.twoPtrValue.ptr1` and is really a `struct List` (which is declared in `tclInt.h` and is *not part of Tcl's public API*). The `struct List` in turn has a variable-length array in it, the `elements` field; don't modify inside there or you'll break things. Dictionaries are similar, but use a `struct Dict` instead (which contains a variation on the theme of hash tables) and which is declared *just* inside `tclDictObj.c`; even the rest of Tcl's implementation can't see how they work internally. That's deliberate.

If you want to debug into a `Tcl_Obj *`, you'll have to proceed carefully, look at the `typePtr`, apply relevant casts where necessary, and make sure you're using a debug build of Tcl with all the symbol and type information preserved.

There's nothing about this that makes debugging a whole array of values particularly easy. The simplest approach is to print the string view of the object, like this:

```
print Tcl_GetString(objv[1])
```

Be aware that this does potentially trigger the serialization of the object (including memory allocation) so it's definitely not perfect. It is, however, really easy to do. (`Tcl_GetString` generates the serialization if necessary — storing it in the `objPtr->bytes` field of course — and returns a pointer to it. This means that the value returned is *definitely* UTF-8. Well, Tcl's internal variation on UTF-8 that's slightly denormalized in a couple of places that probably don't matter to you right now.)

---

Note that you can read some of this information from scripts in Tcl 8.6 (the current recommended release) with the `::tcl::unsupported::representation` command. As you can guess from the name, it's not supported (because it violates a good number of Tcl's basic semantic model rules) but it can help with debugging before you break out the big guns of attaching gdb.